Make a method final and use the base class implementation
I have a hierarchy of polymorphic classes. At some level in the hierarchy, I want to make the implementation of a virtual method final.
Additionally, I just want to use the base class implementation.
My current implementation is:
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void method() final {
        Base::method();
    }
};

Is there a shorter way to do this? Probably a combination of using and final?

You can make the whole class final, if this is "the last level".

If you want to prevent the member function from being overridden, it can also be made virtual and final on the base class level. Not sure though if that's what you want.

I think OP wants something like using Base::Method final; which is NOT valid. I don't think there is a shorter way for what OP wants.
